# Regular expression - to get [A]16, 5, A[20], 15 from "[A]16 and 5th and A[20] and 15"

Tags: c#, regex, expression

I have a string like this - `"[A]16 and 5th and A[20] and 15"`

I need to takes values `[A]16`, `5`, `A[20]`, `15`.  (digits and also [A], if that exists)

I'm using C#.

```
 string[] numbers = Regex.Split("[A]16 and 5th and [A]20 and 15", @"\D+");
```

the code below will give me only digits. But I need also [A] in font of digits (if it exists).

Please, could you help me.

Comment: will you have only [A] or  [B] [C] etc also

Comment: In two early examples in your question you use both `[A]16` and `A[20]` (two different formats), but in the code, you use `[A]16` `[A]20` (same format). If you want a good answer, you've got a ask a good question -- is there a `[B]` or `[C]` or `[G]`? or is there only `[A]`? can it be either `A[200]` _or_ `[A]200`?... will you ever even return to this site to read this comment/question?

Answer (score 1):

The more generic pattern could be:

```
@"\[[A-Z]][0-9]+|[A-Z]\[[0-9]+]|[0-9]+"



[[A-Z]][0-9]       - matches [Letter from A-Z]Number          example: [A]10
or |[A-Z]\[[0-9]+] - matches Letter from A-Z[Number]          example: A[10]
or |[0-9]+         - matches Numers from 1-N                  example: 5, or 15
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this pattern: `@"(\[A\])?\d+"` if there are only `[A]`s.
If you have also `[B]`, `[C]`... you can use this pattern: `@"(\[[A-Z]\])?\d+"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pattern:

```
string lordcheeto = @".*?(\[A\]\d+|\d+|A\[\d+\]).*?";
```

It will also trim the junk from the matches you want. Although, due to the way `Split` works, there will be empty strings in the array. As for the seemingly requisite general case, you can use this:

```
string lordcheeto = @".*?(\[[A-Z]\]\d+|\d+|[A-Z]\[\d+\]).*?";
```

**Code**

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace RegExIssues
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Properly escaped to capture matches.
            string lordcheeto = @".*?(\[A\]\d+|\d+|A\[\d+\]).*?";
            string input = "[A]16 and 5th and A[20] and 15";

            executePattern("lordcheeto's", input, lordcheeto);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void executePattern(string version, string input, string pattern)
        {
            // Avoiding repitition for this example.
            Console.WriteLine("Using {0} pattern:", version);

            // Needs to be trimmed.
            var result = Regex.Split(input.Trim(), pattern);

            // Pipe included to highlight empty strings.
            foreach (var m in result)
                Console.WriteLine("|{0}", m);

            // Extra space.
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

**Test**

http://goo.gl/VNqpp

**Output**

```
Using lordcheeto's pattern:
|
|[A]16
|
|5
|
|A[20]
|
|15
|
```

**Comments**

If you need anything more or this breaks with other strings, let me know and I can probably modify it.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```
(\[[A-Z]\][0-9]+)|([A-Z]\[[0-9]+\])|([0-9]+)
```

**Demo :**

http://regexr.com?30p8v